How do I give my node a parameter of another node?
Is there a nice way, in my launch file, to fech a parameter of another node and use it as my parameter?
Chat proposed to use a console call to read the value, parse it and assign. That works, but it is a hack. Is there any way to do it within the ros system, without going low level?
Context: I am making a node with moveit planner interface, which wants robot description + semantic. Description is ok as it is passed as a topic, but the semantic is not. The xArm setup uses complicated system of launch files with droves of params and xacros, which I do not want to redundantly replicate. I want to use the already final semantic that is present as a param of move_group.
Note: this is not a question about moveIt or xArm. The context is here to exaplain why I don't "just load the srdf".
